# Random number from integer array? C in uVision 4

Tags: c, arrays, int, arm, stm32f4discovery

I am coding on uVision 4 in C for a ARM assignment.
I can't seem to figure it out but every time I keep on getting the string "536876144".

```
int main(void) {

    int binary[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};//I want this array as integers (for binary terms), therefore i can toggle each number as 1 or 0, corresponding to the input.
    char stringbinary[9]; //string for recording the value of the converted integer array
    sprintf(stringbinary, "%d", binary);//conversion of the array to string
    printf("%s\r\n",stringbinary);//printing the value
          .............
          .............

          if(input=1){
          binary[0]=1 - binary[0]; // I have the each value of the array to toggle with activation
          }

}
```

It may just be because I'm tired after hours of coding. I'm pretty sure it's something simple and basic but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: `if(input=1)` should be `if(input == 1)`, and `int binary[8] = {0}`; is enough, remaining parts will be implicitly initialized to 0

Comment: the result is not "random" as you said, it's the address of `binary`

Answer (score 2):

Your statement:

```
sprintf(stringbinary, "%d", binary);//conversion of the array to string
```

indicates that you misunderstand how to convert an array of integers to a string.

The line above will take the address of `binary`, convert it to an integer, and print the address as an integer.

If you want to print `binary` to `stdout` without any spaces between the numbers, you can use:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
{
   printf("%d", binary[i]);
}
print("\n");
```

Make sure you add a line

```
int i;
```

at the start of the function before you use that `for` loop.